# Apex Batch Test Class for Opps with OLIs not returning values

Tags: unit-test, batch, opportunity-lineitem

I'm struggling with an Test Class for a little batch I created, let me clarify that I'm not a developer, so any tips will be appreciated.

I wrote 2 versions of the class, the first gives me about 94% coverage, but I was not creating products and pricebook entries in the class, so I changed it to add those and the code coverage went down to 83%. The test passes everytime, but the system assert fails.

Here's my class

```
global class batchCalculateMRR implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    String query = 'SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Vigente__c, Es_Recurrente__c, TotalPrice, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE HasOpportunityLineItem = TRUE';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> oppsWithProducts)
{

List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    for (Opportunity oppWithProduct : oppsWithProducts) {
        System.debug('Opp Id: '+ oppWithProduct.Id);

        //List<Double> toSum = new List<Double>();
        Double MRRSum = 0.0;

        for (OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem : oppWithProduct.OpportunityLineItems) {
            System.debug('Opp Line Item: ' + oppLineItem.Id);

            if (oppLineItem.Vigente__c == TRUE && oppLineItem.Es_Recurrente__c == TRUE) {
            //toSum.add(oppLineItem.TotalPrice);
            System.debug('To Sum: ' + oppLineItem.TotalPrice);
            MRRSum = MRRSum + oppLineItem.TotalPrice;
            } else if (oppLineItem.Vigente__c == FALSE && oppLineItem.Es_Recurrente__c == TRUE 
                        || oppLineItem.Vigente__c == TRUE && oppLineItem.Es_Recurrente__c == FALSE
                        || oppLineItem.Vigente__c == FALSE && oppLineItem.Es_Recurrente__c == FALSE) {
                    //toSum.add(0.0);
                    System.debug('To Sum: ' + 0.0);
                    MRRSum = MRRSum + 0.0;
            }
        }
        //System.debug('Total Price to Sum: '+ toSum.size());
        //System.debug(toSum);
        System.debug('Final MRRSum: ' + MRRSum);

        //Create List to Update Opps
        oppWithProduct.MRR_Test_JB__c = MRRSum;
        oppsToUpdate.add(oppWithProduct);
        //System.debug('MRR Test JB'+ oppWithProduct.MRR_Test_JB__c);
        }
                Update oppsToUpdate;
}  


global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
```

And the test class I'm currently working on:

```
    //See PriceBook
    Id priceBookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    //Create your products
    Product2 firstProduct = new Product2(
        Name = 'First Product',
        ProductCode = 'Pro-1',
        isActive = true,
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert firstProduct;

    Product2 secondProduct = new Product2(
        Name = 'Second Product',
        ProductCode = 'Pro-2',
        isActive = true,
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert secondProduct;

    Product2 thirdProduct = new Product2(
        Name = 'Third Product',
        ProductCode = 'Pro-3',
        isActive = true,
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert thirdProduct;


    //Create your pricebook entries      
    PricebookEntry firstPricebookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
        Product2Id = firstProduct.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10.00,
        IsActive = true,
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert firstPricebookEntry;

    PricebookEntry secondPricebookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
        Product2Id = secondProduct.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10.00,
        IsActive = true,
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert secondPricebookEntry;

    PricebookEntry thirdPricebookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
        Product2Id = thirdProduct.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10.00,
        IsActive = true,
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert thirdPricebookEntry;

    //Create Opportunities
    List<Opportunity> newOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Integer i=0 ;i <100;i++) {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name ='Name'+i;
        opp.StageName = '1.Contactando al decisor';
        opp.Pricebook2Id = priceBookId;
        opp.CloseDate =  Date.today();
        opp.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        newOpps.add(opp);
    }
    insert newOpps;

    //Create Opportunity Line Items
    List<OpportunityLineItem> newOlis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for (Opportunity newOpp : newOpps) {

        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli.OpportunityId = newOpp.Id;
        oli.TotalPrice = firstPricebookEntry.UnitPrice;
        //oli.Product2Id = firstProduct.Id;
        oli.PricebookEntryId = firstPricebookEntry.Id;
        oli.End_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(+1);
        oli.Es_Recurrente__c = True;
        oli.Quantity = 1;
        oli.Es_upselling__c = 'False';
        newOlis.add(oli);

        OpportunityLineItem oli2 = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli2.OpportunityId = newOpp.Id;
        oli2.TotalPrice = secondPricebookEntry.UnitPrice;
        //oli2.Product2Id = secondProduct.Id;
        oli2.PricebookEntryId = secondPricebookEntry.Id;
        oli2.End_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(-5);
        oli2.Es_Recurrente__c = True;
        oli2.Quantity = 1;
        oli2.Es_upselling__c = 'False';
        newOlis.add(oli2);

        OpportunityLineItem oli3 = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli3.OpportunityId = newOpp.Id;
        oli3.TotalPrice = thirdPricebookEntry.UnitPrice;
        //oli3.Product2Id = thirdProduct.Id;
        oli3.PricebookEntryId= thirdPricebookEntry.Id;
        oli3.End_Date__c = Date.today();
        oli3.Es_Recurrente__c = True;
        oli3.Quantity = 1;
        oli3.Es_upselling__c = 'False';
        newOlis.add(oli3);
    }
    insert newOlis;

    Test.startTest();

        batchCalculateMRR batchCalculateMRR_Test= new batchCalculateMRR();
        DataBase.executeBatch(batchCalculateMRR_Test); 

    Test.stopTest();

    //Validate Opportunity MRR_Test_JB__c
    List<Opportunity> oppsAssert = [SELECT Id, MRR_Test_JB__c FROM Opportunity];
    for (Opportunity oppAssert : oppsAssert) {
        System.debug(oppAssert.MRR_Test_JB__c);
        System.assertEquals(20.0, oppAssert.MRR_Test_JB__c);
    }
}
```

The problem is, in the debug logs I see all 100 Opps each with 3 OLIs but the field MRR_Test_JB__c (which should be updated in the actual batch class) is empty so my System.assertEquals fails.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!!

Comment: What's your batch class do? In particular, what query does it run in `start()`?

Comment: @DavidReed I added the batch class to the question.

Comment: N.B. you can simply do an `update oppsWithProduct` instead of creating a new list at the end of `execute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the field `MRR_Test_JB__c` only updates with the `TotalPrice` if:

```
oppLineItem.Vigente__c == TRUE && oppLineItem.Es_Recurrente__c == TRUE
```

But in your test, you are only setting the OpportunityLineItems' `Es_Recurrente__c` field to true, and not `Vigente__c` so the batch is always adding 0.0 instead of the `TotalPrice`

I'm not sure why you need the "else if" logic (i.e., if `Vigente__c` or `Es_Recurrente__c` aren't true) at all, since adding 0.0 doesn't affect the MRR_Test_JB__c amount.

Comment: Vigente__c is actually a formula field which checks the ServiceDate and End_Date__c. I was giving it a date for End_Date__c but not for ServiceDate so nothing was happening!  

I'll try removing the else if part! I'm new to this, so I'm still learning!

Thank you!!

Comment: I removed the else if and I got 100% coverage! Thanks again!